# Acer aspire 5520 power light blinks no boot

Tags: boot

My laptop was working fine last night, I hibernated it and went to sleep. Got up, pressed the power button. The power light comes on for 4 seconds and the hdd light blinked a few times, then it turned off for a second then repeats the process. The only way to stop this process/power down is to remove the AC and take out the battery.

It does not even reach a boot screen, nothing shows up on the screen, fan does not start. People on [this forum](http://www.wimsbios.com/forum/topic11831.html) has the same problem but they suggest to put the laptop in a oven and heat it (reflow).
What could be the problem? Is there another solution other than a reflow? I dont feel like putting my motherboard in the oven.

Answer (score 1):

A suggested fix for some Acer laptop power-up problems is to do the following:

1. Remove the battery and external
   power
2. Hold down the power switch for
   30-40 seconds
3. Plug in the external
   power cord
4. Power up the laptop
5. Reinsert the battery

Comment: You can remove or insert laptop batteries while it is on? Cool.

Answer (score 0):

It normally works if you change the CMOS battery in the motherboard

It is commom problem in Acer Travelmate 5200 series laptops

Comment: Do you have a source for that?